# Use of <? extends T> in collection

Tags: java, generics, collections, extends, super

Please do not close this question without giving me a proper argument what I am trying to say here.
Well, I have seen many answers on this subject but please allow me to put my thoughts here.
Consider a simple code below:

```
class B extends A{}
class C extends B{}
class D extends C{}
```

Now lets make a list

```
List <? extends B> = new ArrayList<B>();
```

In the above code I have told compiler that there a list and it can contain B or any subclass of B.

Now the compiler knows that the list can contain  B or C or D. The compiler has been specified to hold B,C or D.

Now when I try to add type of B, C or D to the list it doesnt allow.

We had already told compiler that we are dealing with B or any subclass of B.

The explanation given is that we can not be sure what the list might be containing so we can not add.

Where doea the question of any uncertainty arises?  we know very well that we are dealing with B,C and D so we can read type of B,C, D and should be able to add type of B or C or D. The question of uncertainty ends right when I am actually creating a list that means  either   a B new ArrayList() or a C new ArrayList() or  a D new ArrayList()

In short: Why they didnt design it this way below:
if I declare a list like:

```
List<? extends  B> list_dealing_wt_BCD  = new ArrayList<C>();
//I should be allowed to add B,C and D.

List<? super  B> list_dealing_wt_A  = new ArrayList<A>();
//I should be allowed to add A.
```

**am I missing something big here:)**

Comment: Because `List<? extends B>` _could be_ a `List<SubB>`, to which it is not legal to add a `B`.

Comment: why List <SubB> not legal when I have already specified Type B .when I created the list?

Comment: You told the compiler to forget that the type is `List<B>`. From then on, it only considers it a `List<? extends B>`.

Comment: your point is taken. Tell me what would break if Java 1.18 comes and starts allowing it. Thats the point I am arguing it. if I write var A= "SomeString" .Here compiler is smart to knwo the type. on the same line why compiler can not remember that  the type the list is supposed to contain.

Comment: _Because you explicitly told it to forget._

Comment: You are saying that by declaring a type List<? extends B> I told it to forget! On the contrary I have told it to allow B or any subclass of B. Ok anyways my question is if I you were to change the design of java and start allowing adding to a list declared like   List<? extends B>  list = new ArrayList<C>() tell me where would it fail.